# Add two extra filter of 1 collection using mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native

I have 4 collections:

**users**

```
users: { id: '123123123', name: 'MrMins' }
```

**matches**

```
{ id: 1, team1: 23, team2: 24, date: '6/14', matchday: 1, locked: false, score1: null, score2: null }
{ id: 2, team1: 9, team2: 32, date: '6/15', matchday: 1, locked: false, score1: null, score2: null }
```

**countries**

```
{id: 23, country: "Russia", pais: "Rusia", group: 'A' }
{id: 24, country: "Saudi Arabia", pais: "Arabia Saudita", group: 'A' }
{id: 9, country: "Egypt", pais: "Egipto", group: 'A' }
{id: 32, country: "Uruguay", pais: "Uruguay", group: 'A' }
```

**forecast**

```
{ matchid: 1, score1: 3, score2: 4, userid: '123123123' }
{ matchid: 2, score1: 3, score2: 0, userid: '123123123' }
```

My query:

```
db.collection('matches').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'countries',
          localField: 'team1',
          foreignField: 'id',
          as: 'team1'
        }
    },{
        $lookup: {
          from: 'countries',
          localField: 'team2',
          foreignField: 'id',
          as: 'team2'
        }
    }
    ]).toArray(function(err, res) {
      callback(err, res);
    });
```

Just now, I have the relation between `matches`, and `countries` (two times).
How I can add the additional filter to `forecast` doing a relation with `matchid` and `userid` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$lookup` works as left outer join but it inserts "joined" results as an array in your document. So every field you add (using `as` option) will be an array.

To get data both from `forecasts` and `users` you have to transform that array into an object and you can do it using [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) operator:

```
db.matches.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'countries',
          localField: 'team1',
          foreignField: 'id',
          as: 'team1'
        }
    },{
        $lookup: {
          from: 'countries',
          localField: 'team2',
          foreignField: 'id',
          as: 'team2'
        }
    },{
        $lookup: {
          from: 'forecast',
          localField: 'id',
          foreignField: 'matchid',
          as: 'forecast'
        }
    }, {
        $addFields: {
          forecast: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$forecast", 0 ] }
        }
    },{
        $lookup: {
          from: 'users',
          localField: 'forecast.userid',
          foreignField: 'id',
          as: 'forecast.user'
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: But, there, how I can add the filter by user?
Because, right now is doing a full join between those tables

Comment: the forecast attached is case exist, based in the user id, like a left join

Answer (score 1):

It will be quite simple using the **mongodb 3.6** `$lookup` version with using nested pipeline

```
db.matches.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'countries',
      let: { 'team1': '$team1' },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ '$id', '$$team1' ] } }}
      ],
      as: 'team1'
    }
  },{
    $lookup: {
      from: 'countries',
      let: { 'team2': '$team2' },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ '$id', '$$team2' ] } }}
      ],
      as: 'team2'
    }
  }, {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'forecast',
      let: { "match_id": "$id" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ '$matchid', '$$match_id' ] } }},
        { $lookup: {
          from: 'users',
          let: { 'userid': '$userid' },
          pipeline: [
            { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ '$id', '$$userid' ] } }}
          ],
          as: 'user'
        }}
      ],
      as: 'forecast'
    }
  }
])
```